# CMSMarkStackSizeMax param in JVM 8

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, java-7

We have recently changed the JDK version from 1.7 to 1.8.

We are running normal JVM process with the below Memory Arguments , please below is just the snippet of the same.

```
MEM_ARGS="-DTENURED_SIZE=5G -Xms10G -Xmx10G -DCONSERVATIVE_ZONE=0 -DMEMORY_PANIC_DISABLE=YES "
-XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:SurvivorRatio=3
GC_ARGS="-XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:+CMSPrecleanRefLists1 " 
GC_ARGS="$GC_ARGS -XX:+CMSPrecleanRefLists2 " 
GC_ARGS="$GC_ARGS -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled " 
GC_ARGS="$GC_ARGS -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark " 
GC_ARGS="$GC_ARGS -XX:PrintCMSStatistics=2 " 
GC_ARGS="$GC_ARGS -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly " 
GC_ARGS="$GC_ARGS -XX:CMSMarkStackSize=4m  "
GC_ARGS="$GC_ARGS -XX:CMSMarkStackSizeMax=5G " 
GC_ARGS="$GC_ARGS -XX:ParGCDesiredObjsFromOverflowList=20k " 
GC_ARGS="$GC_ARGS -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC  "
GC_ARGS="$GC_ARGS -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=40 " 
GC_ARGS="$GC_ARGS -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime  "
GC_ARGS="$GC_ARGS -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow  "
```

When we start the JVM we are receiving the below error in our log

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0

> MarkStackSizeMax of 5368709120 is invalid; must be between 1 and
>   2147483646 Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A
>   fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

What is the issue with MarkStackSize why we need to reduce it to less than 2 GB when same 5G value was working fine in JDK1.7?

Apart from this what is the MarkStackSize I could not find any information about the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Marking stack is the structure for traversing the reachable object graph during marking phase of GC.

[JDK-8000244](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8000244) added the range check for `MarkStackSizeMax` argument.
The [upper limit](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/hsx/hsx25/hotspot/rev/442f942757c0#l4.40) is now `(max_jint - 1)`.

I can't imagine a case when a larger value may be ever needed, so I suggest to simply remove the argument and let JVM choose the default. Most likely, this will not affect the performance anyway.